# Not finding php.ini include_path

Tags: php, include-path

I have just set up virtual hosts on a windows machine (using xampp) and made an entry for my default site as follows.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "D:/path/to/my/website"
ServerName localhost

<Directory "D:/path/to/my/Website">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I then commented out the include_path in c:\xamp\php\php.ini so I can run multiple sites each with their own include_path

I have an .htaccess file with no path defined in the localhost root directory. 
I have a php.ini file with a path defined as follows: include_path = ".;D:\path\to\my\website\php"
But when I run phpinfo, I get the default include_path= .;C:\php\pear

Any ideas why php does not see my php.ini? I've checked everywhere for stray .htaccess files or php.ini files but this is the root of the server and the only files are the ones I've mentioned.

Comment: check the phpinfo() output to see what php.ini filr your php reads. This is the file (and only this) u can use under your Apache. Modify the include path in the bootsrap of each of your sub sites. (php_ini_set)

Comment: Loaded Configuration File = C:\xampp\php\php.ini and Configuration File (php.ini) Path = C:\Windows (but no php.ini here)

Comment: I thought I'd force the issue and removed php.ini from \xampp\php thinking you can only have one php.ini file and this would force it to read the one at localhost and ... instead I got Loaded Configuration File (none). Perhaps there is a setting for where to find the php.ini file (e.g. the configuration file path of c:\windows)? I am using set_include_path() for now, but would like to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

php.ini, for apache module, is set **in compile time (of PHP)**.
Put back the erase php.ini file there (right now, mod-php uses default values).

For multiple vhosts, either use (check if possible) apache config, either in htaccess or in specific vhost config file, Or use the php ini set function of PHP.

Both are good practice, unless u really really need every last juice out of your system, in which case, PHP is not the technology u should have chosen.

Comment: I tried using set_include_path() but this had too many repercussions. I am currently using the php_value include_path directive in .htaccess and this seems to be a straight swap for using the php.ini file as it is global to the whole site. I would like to know how to reconfigure Apache and I will look into it. However, the vhost config sounds very promising. I will look into it as well to see if there are additional settings.